Ponto em vez de terminar aspas?
Estou lendo um livro de um autor brasileiro ("A queda e outros contos de ficção científica" de Hugo Puertas de Araújo). Tenho notado um aspeto da tipografia para o que gostaria de conhecer a regra:
Nesse livro, onde há aspas ao final de uma frase, o ponto final muitas vezes parece acabar as aspas sem haber aspas finais. Três exemplos da mesma página (54):
1)


Aqui diz: “Túnel de manutenção 13 - Setor C6. E aqui é a chave de “Liga”.






(...), mas Paula simplesmente digitou “1234” e teclou o “Enter. A tela mudou e e passou a apresentar um conjunto de linhas e pontos (...)





No topo da tela o título dizia “Trocadores de calor atmosférico.

Tenho procurado explicações em internet, mas só podia achar discussões sobre pôr o ponto final dentro ou fora das aspas, não omitir-o completamente.
Acho que no exemplo 2) é interessante a instância de “1234” com as aspas finais que não está no final da frase, e também “Liga” no exemplo 1) que sim está a última palavra da frase e ainda tem as aspas finais.
Há regra sobre isso? E se há, como aplicamos as "aspas com ponto final" se a frase citada mesma contém ponto (p.ex. "Não tocar. Perigo de morte.") sem ter final de citação ambígua?

Esse livro foi publicado por quem? Uma casa editora ou auto-publicado? Pode fazer uma diferença em termos de revisão da redação. Dito isso, acho que sempre se usa aspas duas vezes.

@Lambie: Parece que foi auto-publicado. Talvez deveria extender a pergunta para se não é "regra oficial", ainda me interessa se é convenção ou estilo informal popular.

Acho que nunca se usa só uma vez. É preciso abrir e fechar as aspas. Se for uma citação inteira, se coloca depois do ponto final. Se for uma trecho citado, não. Como você disse: "Não tocar. Perigo de morte." Mas: Ele falou "não tocar". :) As auto-publicações muitas vezes sofrem de revisão mal feita.

Nunca vi isso, e acharia inclusive melhor usa aspas simples dentro de aspas duplas; p.ex., "Eu apertei a tecla 'Enter' e fui para à próxima linha".

@Schilive Sim, claro. Existem vários casos de figure mas não aspas só uma vez.

@Lambie, realmente.

Opa.  Casos de figura.
